# How can I use remote in iparallel to ensure that the engines generated by the master and slave machines are in the same comm.world?

Tags: python, ipython, mpi, mpi4py

The environment used is Jupyter notebook with ipyparallel. After executing the following command in PowerShell:

ipcontroller --profile=remote --ip=140.117.111.XXX

It will generate a file called 'ipcontroller-remote-engine.json'. Then, copy this JSON file to the remote slave machine. On the slave machine, open PowerShell and enter the following command:

ipcluster start -n 2 --profile=remote

This will create two engines. However, these two engines are not in the same comm.world as the engines generated by the master. What should I do to make the engines created by the master and the slave machine belong to the same comm.world?

I expecting the engine generated from master and slave machine are in same comm.world
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nEQ79.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dZhih.png)

The in front of the two are at master machine, others are at slave machine.
but they are not in identical comm.world.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9HoYv.png)